# Derivative of an absolutely continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let's say that I have two absolutely continuous functions on an interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$, call them $f_1,f_2$. Fix also an open subset of $I$, call it $E$. Assume that $g:=f_1\chi_E+f_2\chi_{E^c}$ is absolutely continuous.

The problem is: is it true that $g^{\prime} = f_1^{\prime}\chi_E+f^{\prime}_{2} \chi_{E^c}$ almost everywhere ? This looks like a stupid question but I can't really prove it. Can somebody help me? Thank you!

$\mathbf{Edit}$: Initially I asked the question for a general Borel subset. Then I realized that it was sufficient for $E$ to be open, but if someone has a general proof I will be curious to see it.

Comment: It need not be the case that $\partial E$ has zero measure. Consider the complement of a fat Cantor set.

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous, we have $f_1 = f_2$ on $\partial E$.  But we must show (somehow) because $g$ is **absolutely** continuous, we have $f_1' = f_2'$ a.e. on $\partial E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have $g' = f_1'\chi_E + f_2'\chi_{E^c}$ almost everywhere.

Let $D$ be the set where $g'$ exists, $D_i$ the set where $f_i'$ exists, $i = 1,2$. Further let $A$ be the set of Lebesgue points of $\chi_E$. Then the complement of $F := D \cap D_1 \cap D_2 \cap A$ is a null set, and we have
$$g'(x) = f_1'(x)\chi_{E}(x) + f_2'(x)\chi_{E^c}(x)$$
for all $x \in F$.

Suppose that $x \in F \cap E$. Since $x$ is a point of density of $E$, there are sequences $(x_n)$ in $E \setminus \{x\}$ with $x_n \to x$. For such a sequence we have
$$g'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(x_n) - g(x)}{x_n - x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_1(x_n) - f_1(x)}{x_n - x} = f_1'(x) = f_1'(x)\chi_E(x) + f_2'(x)\chi_{E^c}(x)\,.$$
The proof for $x \in F \setminus E$ is similar.

(This works for all Borel sets $E \subset I$.)

Comment: Thanks, very clear!